# Simplifying C++ Nested-For Loop

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I have this code:

```
Mat src;
Mat dst;
Mat mean;
uchar tab[768];
for(i = 0; i< size.height; i++) {
    const uchar* sdata = src.ptr(i);
    const uchar* mdata = mean.ptr(i);
    uchar* ddata = dst.ptr(i);
    for(j = 0; j < size.width; j++) {
        ddata[j] = tab[sdata[j] - mdata[j] + 255];
    }
}
```

Basically I am trying to calculate the idx value for **tab**, use this idx to get the value in tab then assign it to **ddata**.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Comment: `for(j = 0; i< size.width; j++) {` is wrong. make sure the code is correct before trying to optimize it

Comment: also `ddata[j]` is overwritten in every iteration of the outer loop, that doesnt look right either

Comment: what's even the purpose of these acrobatics? lots of uninitialized variables, with no mention of what they're supposed to mean. and why not use `cv::Mat::at()`? all I see is a pixel-wise subtraction followed by an application of a look-up table. if you want to improve this, use OpenCV methods. don't write your own loop. you don't even use parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that 2 dimensional matrices are 1 dimension in memory :

```
Mat src;
Mat dst;
Mat mean;
uchar tab[768];
const int maxI = size.width * size.height;
for(i = 0; i< maxI; i++) {
    dst.ptr(i) = tab[src.ptr(i) - mean.ptr(i) + 255];
}
```

On top of this, you can use pointers to avoid having to recompute the data position from the index at each loop :

```
Mat src;
Mat dst;
Mat mean;
uchar tab[768];
const uchar* sdata = src.ptr(0);
const uchar* mdata = mean.ptr(0);
uchar* ddata = dst.ptr(0);
const int maxI = size.width * size.height;
for(i = 0; i< maxI; ++i) {
    *ddata++ = tab[*sdata++ - *mdata++ + 255];
}
```

NOTE : On the second example I changed the i++ in the loop to ++i. Theorically this can be faster, although you should measure there to see if this really changes something.

Also, this code is not taking advantage of parallelism. You can take advantage of multiple cores by using multithreading to make it run faster. This is another topic, and if you want to go this route this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68925741/thread-safe-array-counter-c/68929518#68929518) has some answers that you might find interesting.